# Combination of .load() and setTimeout() to refresh a shopping card indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

In order to update the shopping cart $ total and item total we are using an AJAX call to replace the contents of the cart summary div (#cart-summary-for-ajax) by pulling the data from another (smaller) page on the same site.

The problem we are facing is that in order to get this to work, we receive an error within the .js file which prevents another area of the code from working (an onFocus effect that changes the opacity of a totally different div).

```
setTimeout('$('#cart-summary-for-ajax').load('http://###.com.au/pages/contact #cart-summary-for-ajax');', 500);
```

The confusing thing is that if I instead use the following code, the onFocus effect I mentioned works perfectly, there's no error in the file but the AJAX appears not to happen.

```
setTimeout('$('#cart-summary-for-ajax').load('http://###.com.au/pages/contact #cart-summary-for-ajax')', 500);
```

Comment: I see syntax errors in you posted code, do you know you have to escape special characters in strings?

Comment: Musa, which character is the special character? (and unfortunately I was not aware).

Comment: If you use single quote `'` to specify a string then you need to escape all single quotes `'` in the string eg. `'How\'s it going'`. you use `\` to escape characters

Comment: That `` above should have been ```\```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#cart-summary-for-ajax').load('http://a-j-e.com.au/pages/contact #cart-summary-for-ajax');
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks Blaster. This fixed the problem almost entirely, the only odd thing now is that the add to cart button doesn't reset...

Problem is as good as solved though.